# Searching dropdown list in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

Is there a way to search for items in a dropdown list in Google Forms?  If you have a lot of items to choose from, can you start typing to either eliminate other choices or search for choices with the exact words being typed?

Answer (score -1):

If the list is alphabetically sorted, and you expand the drop-down itself and begin typing, Google Forms will jump to the correct place in the list.